# Copying Server SQL table from one server to another

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to copy data from one SQL Server to another SQL Server. But since the data size is almost 70 TB, I need the fastest way to transfer it. I know about `sp_addlinkedserver` and using `BulkUpload` in SSIS. Can anyone suggest which is most efficient way to transfer data in my case scenario and compare the transfer rate of different methods?
PS- I have azure transfer as an option too but physical transfer of disk is just not an option.

Comment: It doesn't matter what path you choose. Copying 70TB is going to take a damn long time. With that much data making a backup, copying that to the new destination and restoring is probably the quickest.

Comment: Agreed with @Sean above -- 70TB of data is 70TB of data, and copying over the wire will take the same amount of time for 70TB no matter what format. I would also suggest backing up the data and then see if you can compress it somehow. If you're luck and can get it compressed you will reduce your 70TB of data. Or call AWS and get an AWS Snowball (if you're on AWS).

Comment: See [How to move a fairly large tsql table from one server to another server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/97852/91898)

Comment: I would consider writing the data out to disk (possibly as .bak), remove the drive, move the drive to the other server, mount it, and move the data into the sql server. 70tb over network is a lot to move over the wire.

Comment: How often? How stale can the data be? How far away is the other server? You could have the active database on a RAID set, mirror it on-the-fly, pull out the mirrored drives and place them in an innertube to float downstream to the other server. One large packet, delivered slowly.

Comment: Physical transfer of drive is simply not an option. And I work on Azure! So any other alternative?